# Error reading csv file using function parameters in two modules in PYTHON

Tags: python, function, csv, module

Have a issue in reading CSV file. I am a new-bee, so an updated code with explanation/ guidance will be nice. Thanks in advance!

When I try to read from the CSV file, it cannot read. Please HELP!

Attention required at ---->>>>>>>.     def reading_in

---

```
#Frontend
## Code block to import information
import sys
import backend

## Code Block to return error when no option selected
def get_non_emty_str(user_prompt):
    sys.stdout.write(user_prompt)
    user_input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    while(user_input==""):
        sys.stdout.write("Error! Cannot be empty! \n" + user_prompt)
        user_input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    return user_input

#Code block to check if the entered number is one of the following choices 
def get_non_emty_int(user_prompt):
    # List for approved item selection
    plan_plan = ["0","1","2"]
    # Function call to check non empty field
    user_input= get_non_emty_str(user_prompt)
    # Loop code to check approved selections
    while not user_input in plan_plan:
        sys.stdout.write("Error! Select a correct number! \n" + user_prompt)
        user_input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    else:
        return user_input
    

# Main program code block     
def main():
    ## Declare variable for list
    plans = []
    plans.append( backend.init() )
    plans.append( backend.init() )
    plans.append( backend.init() )

    # Variable for LIST to read from file
    name1 =[]
    surname1 =[]
    plan_index1 =[]
    #declaring empty variable
    user_input=""
    

    # User  MENU code block
    menu="\n========================================\n"
    menu+="   Welcome to MyTFLIX  customer Menu\n"
    menu+="========================================\n"
    menu+="[A]dd new MyTFLIX customer\n"
    menu+="[D]isplay all MyTFLIX customers\n"
    menu+="[E]xclusive MyTFLIX customers to a plan\n"
    menu+="[W]rtie to file\n"
    menu+="[R]ead from file\n"
    menu+="E[x]it\n"
    menu+="========================================\n"
    menu+="Enter choice : "
    user_choice=get_non_emty_str(menu)
    
    # Code execution on user selected input
    while(user_choice.lower()!="x"):
        
        #Code block to add new customer
        if ( user_choice.lower()=="a" ):
            name = get_non_emty_str("Enter customer first name : ")
            surname = get_non_emty_str("Enter customer surname: ")
            
            name_surname = name+" "+surname
            plan_index = int(get_non_emty_int("Select MyTFLIX Plan: [0]-Basic | [1]-HD | [2]-4k : "))
            backend.add_plan(plans[plan_index],name_surname)
            
        # Code block to display all customers    
        elif(user_choice.lower()=="d"):
            if len(plans) == 0:
                sys.stdout.write("No plans to display \n")
                continue
            longest = len(plans[0])
            i=1
            while(i<len(plans)):
                if (longest<len(plans[i])):
                    longest=len(plans[i])
                i+=1
            i=0
            while(i<longest):
                output=""
                blank=" "*25
                if (i<len(plans[0])):
                    output+=f"{plans[0][i]:25}"
                else:
                    output+=blank
                if (i<len(plans[1])):
                    output+=f"{plans[1][i]:25}"
                else:
                    output+=blank
                if (i<len(plans[2])):
                    output+=f"{plans[2][i]:25}"
                else:
                    output+=blank
                sys.stdout.write(output+"\n")
                i+=1
                sys.stdout.flush()
                                
                
        ## Code block to display customers subscription exclusive to a plan ##       
        elif(user_choice.lower()=="e"):
            plan_index = int(get_non_emty_int("\nEnter MyTFLIX plan ID: [0]-Basic | [1]-HD | [2]-4k :"))
            exclusive_to_plan=backend.find_exclusive(plans,plan_index)
            if len(exclusive_to_plan)<1:
                        sys.stdout.write("No exclusive plans to display: \n")

            else:
                i=0
                while(i<len(exclusive_to_plan)):
                    sys.stdout.write(exclusive_to_plan[i]+"\n") 
                    i+=1
                    
                   

        # Write customer data to a csv file
        elif(user_choice.lower()=="w"):
            backend.writing_out(plans)
            
                                               
            
        # Code block to Read customer data from a csv file
        elif(user_choice.lower()=="r"):
            backend.reading_in(plan_index1,name1,surname1)  ## change plan to planindex1,name1,surname1
            
                             
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("\nIncorrect choice!\n")
        user_choice=get_non_emty_str(menu)
    

main()
```

---

### The below reading_in function is giving issue...any solutions

```
#backend
import sys

#Code block to initiate customer MyTFLIX subscription
def init():
    subscription = []
    return subscription

#Code block to add a MyTFLIX customer to the list
def add_plan(subscription,name_surname):    
    subscription.append(name_surname)


# Code block for finding exclusive MyTFLIX customer subscribed a plan
def find_exclusive(plans,plan_index):
    results=[]
    i=0
    while(i<len(plans[plan_index])):        
        matches=0
        d=0
        while(d<len(plans) and matches==0):
            if (d!=plan_index):
                j=0
                while(j<len(plans[d]) and plans[plan_index][i]!=plans[d][j]):
                      j+=1
                if j<len(plans[d]):
                    matches+=1
            d+=1
        if (matches==0):
            results.append(plans[plan_index][i])
        i+=1
    return results
    
# Write out to a csv file function code block
def writing_out(plans):
    sys.stdout.write("Specify file name ending with  .csv to save to: ")
    user_d_file = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    lines_to_write =""
    len_plans= len(plans)
    plan_id=0
    while(plan_id<len_plans):
        
        len_plans_dealer_id = len(plans[plan_id])
        subscription_id=0
        while(subscription_id < len_plans_dealer_id):

            line = str(plan_id)+","
            name_surname = plans[plan_id][subscription_id].split(" ")
            line+= name_surname[0]+","+name_surname[1]+"\n"
            lines_to_write+=line
            subscription_id+=1
        plan_id+=1
    try:
        #Code block to Open-Write-Close file
        out_file_obj = open(user_d_file,"a")
        out_file_obj.write(lines_to_write)
        out_file_obj.close()
        sys.stdout.write("Updated database.....")
    except:
        #Code block if unable to write to file
        sys.stdout.write("Did not write to file!")                                                
            

# Read from a csv file code function
def reading_in (plan_index1,name1,surname1):
    sys.stdout.write("Specify file name ending with  .csv to read from : ")
    user_d_file = sys.stdin.readline().strip()   
    #in_file_obj = open(user_d_file,"r")
    with open(user_d_file) as f:
        line=f.readline()
        while (True):
            try:
                line=f.readline()
                print("line here  "+ line)  #### Works upto here###
                fields = line.strip().split(" ")
                print("fieldsx  "+ fields)
                plan_index= int(fields[0])
                print("plan index  "+ plan_index)  
                name = fields[1]
                surname = fields[2]
                name_surname = name + " " + surname
                print("here -ok  "+ name_surname)  
                backend.add_plan(plans[plan_index],name_surname)
                line= in_file_obj.readline()
                sys.stdout.write("Data Loaded....\n")     
                     
            except:
                sys.stdout.write("Error from reading file!\n")
                break
```

Comment: also, add the error message to the question.

Comment: since I have a error capture it displays the error message. I am unable to read from file.